# Email verification link using amazon cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-cognito, email-verification

I'm using AWS Cognito for email verification when user sign up problem that i had faced is it only sends verification code and unable to customize email so that i can redirect user to verify its email on Cognito. Using .net core 2.1 C#.

So far what i have don is sending email verification code using SES provided by amazon.

```
var request = new SignUpRequest
            {
                ClientId = Configuration["AmazonCognito:ClientId"],
                Password = vm.Password,
                Username = vm.Username,
            };

            AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider =
              new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new Amazon.Runtime.AnonymousAWSCredentials());

            SignUpRequest signUpRequest = new SignUpRequest
            {
                ClientId = request.ClientId,
                Username = vm.Username,
                Password = vm.Password
            };
  AttributeType attributeType1 = new AttributeType
            {
                Name = "email",
                Value = vm.Email
            };
            signUpRequest.UserAttributes.Add(attributeType1);

                SignUpResponse result = await  provider.SignUpAsync(signUpRequest);
```

I want to verify user email using email verification link.

Answer (score 2):

Select the desired user pool from `User pools`. Go to `General Settings` > `Message customizations` > Check `Link` at `Verification type` (default is `Code`)